# Why can't we just use a common base class in react native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

In the sample code for react native that is created by the react-cli at :

https://github.com/facebook/react-native

We see that both the `index.ios.js` and the `index.android.js` both have exactly the same code.

I did some refactoring and extracted this code into a common `index.base.js` file and then just re-imported and re-exported it for each device and it works. Can anybody tell my why this duplication exists in the first place?

I know some of the components are specific to each device but to be honest I don't understand why react native is touted as 'learn once and deploy anywhere' when from this refactor I just did you could actually share the same component level code across each device if you wanted to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have just one `index.js`, in fact it is preferred to do it this way over a separate `.ios.js` and `.android.js` files anytime it's possible.

The sample code attempts to show you that *when you need to* you can create those two files, and the right one gets loaded on each platform.

In case the platform specific code is only a small part of a component, you can still put it into one `.js` file and use the `Platform` module to change behaviour depending on platform.

```
import {Platform} from 'react-native'

...

const message = Platform.OS === 'ios'
  ? 'Hello, iOS user!'
  : 'Hello, Android user!'
```

See more on [platform specific code](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/platform-specific-code.html) in the React Native docs.

Comment: Thanks mate, so do you know why Microsoft has released this ReactXP thing if we can already essentially do cross platform with the current implementation?

Comment: Hm, I don't know anything about ReactXP, but it seems to support Windows as well, so maybe that's the main benefit? We are currently building an iOS/Android app with tons of native dependencies, yet we don't have a single platform-specific `.js` file.

Comment: Yeah it does seem weird that everything online is saying nativeScript if you want cross platform but to me it seems react can be cross platform too. I mean even some of the components like https://reactnavigation.org/ can be used. I am looking at nativeScript but thinking react is better.